# Parsing JSON function in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I need to call a JSON function from C# to check the order status.
In the web page the function is called in this way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
      $(".pro_attribute a").each(function (item)
      {
        var sku = $(this).attr("key");
        OutOfStock(sku);
      });
    });

    function OutOfStock(sku)
    {
      $.getJSON(urltothewebsite + "QueryStockStatus?callback=?", { sku: sku, categoryid: "" }, function (data)
      {
        if (data != null)
        {
          if (data.stockStatus == "Sold Out")
          {
            var key = $("a[key='" + sku + "']");
            key.addClass("outof");
            key.append("<div class=\"outof_tip\" style=\"display: none;\">Sold Out</div>");

            //current sku style
            if (sku.toLowerCase() == $("#sku").html().trim().toLowerCase())
            {
              key.attr("class", "active");
            }

            key.hover(function ()
            {
              key.find('.outof_tip').show();
            }, function ()
            {
              key.find('.outof_tip').hide();
            })
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Can someone please give me an example of how I can make a call to:

```
$.getJSON(urltothewebsite + "QueryStockStatus?callback=?", { sku: sku, categoryid: "" }, function (data)
```

I will then parse the result in the variable data in my code. I would also like to know
which library for the JSON part I have to include.

Comment: Look at: HttpWebRequest or WebClient and JSON.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a `GET` request, the params are added to `querystring`. So you can construct a URL by adding params and then do a `GET` request , get response, JSON.Net to deserialize string to required object.

Sample code snippet.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
String data = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://www.example.com/QueryStockStatus?sku={0}&categoryid={1}","sku_param","cat_id_param")); // replace with required params here.
object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data); // use required object type here
```

Comment: A big thanks Arindam Nayak, this was exactly what I needed, and my problem is now solved! :-)